# Angular - How can I watch a cookie value in my controller without causing "Error $digest() iterations reached"

Tags: angularjs

I have an app where users add items to their cart.  If they are not logged into the site the items are stored in their cookies.  I am trying to create a a visual indicator of how many items the person has in their cart (i.e. cookiestore) that updates as soon as they add an item.

To do this I have the following code:

**Controller**

```
   $scope.temporaryCart = $cookieStore.get('cart').length;

   $scope.$watch(function () {
      return $cookieStore.get('cart');
    }, function () {
      $scope.temporaryCart = $cookieStore.get('cart').length;
    });
```

And in my partial I have:

```
    <div class="words">{{temporaryCart || 0}}</div>
```

If I do not include the `$scope.$watch` the cart does not update, however, when I do include it, I get:

```
Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [[{"msg":"fn: function () {\n      return $cookieStore.get('cart');\n    }"...
```

Is this the right approach to get real time updates from things like Cookies - or how can I avoid all of the iterations and still track a dynamically updating value stored in cookies or a database?

Comment: more practical to use localStorage than cookies.

Comment: Does that have anything to do with the error?

Comment: $watch is for scope variables. The best thing would be to use do everything with scope variables, watch them for changes, and update the cookie whenever the scope changes.

Comment: That I can work with....Would I even have to use $watch if I were using scope values?   Essentially all I want is to make the text of a paragraph change when the add an item to their cart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To put simply, your "$watched" function returns a different object every time, and so the digest cycle never settles. In other words, the following is true:

```
$cookieStore.put("foo", {v: "bar"});
var c1 = $cookieStore.get("foo");
var c2 = $cookieStore.get("foo");

console.log(c1 === c2); // false
```

(btw, `$cookieStore` is deprecated, but the same would be true with `$cookies.getObject`)

If you *must* use cookies to track variables (certainly, if not a service, `localStorage` and `sessionStorage`, as noted in comments, are more suited for it), you could set a $watch for one of its properties:

```
$scope.$watch(function(){
  return $cookies.getObject("cart").length;
}, function(v){
  $scope.temporaryCart = v;
});
```