# Angular how to automatically update a view when changes happen in local storage?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to update a paragraph in a view when something is added to local storage which, in this case is an array of numbers with the name `cart`.

In my **view** I have:

```
    <div class="words">{{user.cart || "thing"}}</div>
```

In my **controller** I have:

```
  .controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, $window, $location, UserFactory) {
       $scope.user = UserFactory.currentUser || {cart: $window.localStorage.getItem('cart')};
   }
```

If I `console.dir` the `$scope.user` it shows  `{cart: [44, 55]}` (i.e. the right object) but in my view the default `"thing"` is shown (or nothing if I remove the `||` condition.

What is the right way to get an automatic update in the view?

If I add:

```
$scope.$watch(function () {
  return JSON.parse($window.localStorage.getItem('cart'));
}, function (newcart) {
  $scope.user.cart = newcart;
});
```

I get:

```
Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
```

and:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'cart' of null
```

Is there some way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering your previous [cookie question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31777216/angular-how-can-i-watch-a-cookie-value-in-my-controller-without-causing-error), you have an XY problem.

Examine the possibility of using Cart service instead that acts as a model and single source of truth. So you can be sure that once you've called Cart setter method, its property or getter method always reflects cookie/localStorage/whateverStorage state, so you can bind it or watch it as any other JS object on scope.

Things like [js-data-angular (former angular-data)](https://github.com/js-data/js-data-angular) can keep you from re-inventing the wheel for full-featured model but it seems like an overkill for such simple task.